# Android serversocket only reads inputs on the first run

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I am creating a very simple multiplayer android game. The devices share information with each other using sockets/serversockets. The program works fine the first run after compilation, but if I close the application and start it again the program does not work. Here is a snippet of the server code:

```
public void listen() {
        try {
            /**
             * Creates a new server socket. By passing in 0, the device will select any
             * available port that is open. This makes it possible to avoid having to hardcode
             * the port.
             */
            if (serverSocket == null)
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);

            // sets the port to the generated server port
            setLocalPort(serverSocket.getLocalPort());

            // run this until the program stops
            while (!stop) {
                // make the server socket listen for input
                setSocket(serverSocket.accept());
                Log.d(TAG, "Socket opened");

                // creates a buffered reader in order to read the input

                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                // listen for messages
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        // reads the line
                        String line;
                        line = input.readLine();

                        // if the line is not null then call onReceive
                        if (line != null) {
                            onReceive(line);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Received: " + line);
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "received something");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // close the input
                input.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "Socket closed");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When the code works i get the following Logcat messages:

> 05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ Socket opened
>   05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ Received: OK
>   05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ received something
>   05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ Socket closed

However, when it does not work i only get the following:

> 05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ Socket opened
>   05-08 15:00:54.186  11947-11965/com.example.trommemand.playerapp D/NET﹕ Socket closed

I suspect that the problem is that I fail to close all sockets. I have tried to close the serversocket, but that gives me an error due to this line: `setSocket(serverSocket.accept());`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always close your resources in `finally` block.
Try closing the `input.close` in `finally` block... like this:

```
           finally { 

                    try {
                        input.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
```

See if this works..